# wxGrid - RefreshBlock Undocumented Member Function

Tags: wxwidgets

In order to refresh a part of the grid, i.e., when font or alignment changes, I was using the following approach:

```
wxRect rect1=CellToRect(TopLeft);
wxRect rect2=CellToRect(BottomRight);
wxRect r(rect1.GetTopLeft(), rect2.GetBottomRight());

RefreshRect(r);
```

This was refreshing only a part of the intended block and was not working correctly.

From the suggestions of intellisense I came across `RefreshBlock` function and it works correctly. I searched the [docs](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/classwx_grid.html) and have not found any information on it. I wonder if it is not recommended to use `RefreshBlock` for some reason? What does `RefreshBlock` do, does it refresh a block (as the name suggests) or is it equivalent to `Refresh`?

I am using wxWidgets 3.2 on Win10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this function being not documented means it is internal use only. You should check the sources and find which function you should be calling. Or try to send a message to wx-users ML asking how to do it properly.

Comment: @Igor: Thanks. In synch `with RefreshBlock` I used a different approach and now things work as expected. Posted the answer down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `RefreshBlock()` is indeed the best way to do what you want and it was only undocumented by mistake, i.e. we simply forgot to do it. I've added [documentation for it](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_grid.html#a4290740a41cf2613fe1d62f047863b27) only now, so it will only get included in 3.2.1, but you can still use it in your code, the function itself is available since 3.1.3.

Comment: Thanks for that. I realized I have been using it in some other part of the code for a while and it works perfectly well!

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the source [code](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/a3fd6cf4e6ad83c89d05ae5912044d07d90b0527/src/generic/grid.cpp#L5825) that, depending on the location of its parameters, `RefreshBlock` refreshes any of the following:

1. corner grid
2. frozen cols grid
3. frozen rows grid
4. main grid

Since the area I wanted to refresh was on the *main grid* the following approach works (the idea is similar to RefreshBlock's approach):

```
auto GridWnd = CellToGridWindow(TL);
wxRect rect = BlockToDeviceRect(TL, BR, GridWnd);
GetGridWindow()->RefreshRect(rect);
```

Now everything is refreshed correctly.

**Notes:**

1. If only `RefreshRect(rect)` is called, things will NOT work as expected.
2. Little experiment showed that `BlockToDeviceRect(TL, BR)` also works, therefore eliminating the need for `auto GridWnd = CellToGridWindow(TL);`